# How do I force Exchange to redownload emails that have been archived

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-2010

I am trying to recover email from a corrupt PST file.  I have had no luck yet running scanpst.exe.  Is there a way to force exchange to re-download email that has already been archived?

Answer (score 0):

No, when you archive to a PST file, the messages are deleted from Exchange/ You might be able to undelete them (click "Recover Deleted Items" button), but most Exchange servers only keep deleted items for 30 days.